# Side by side visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

How can I change my Visual Studio layout to show the actual HTML page I edit?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [HTML 11](https://vlasovstudio.com/html11/) extension to preview html file editing in Visual Studio.